# nmcli command not running from a java program

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have a java program that connects to a wifi network using fields from the user. I am using nmcli to connect to a wifi network as stated in [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI)

The command `nmcli device wifi connect <SSID|BSSID> password <password>` works absolutely as it should from the command line.

But I want to implement this command from a java program. The main body is as follows:

```
        Process p;
        String command = "nmcli device wifi connect '" + wifiName + "' password " + password;
        System.out.println();
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    p.waitFor();
```

I don't know why but nothing is printed in the console after the command is executed.

Elementary commands like `ping`, etc are working just fine.

**EDIT:**

Used ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.exec

```
Process p;
        String command = "nmcli device wifi connect '" + wifiName + "' password " + password;
        System.out.println();
        p = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

Got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nmcli device wifi connect 'wifiname' password password": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at wificonnect.WifiConnect.main(WifiConnect.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more
/home/oni/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Shells like `bash` understand single quotes (`'`).  Direct execution of commands does not understand them.  You would be wise to use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.exec.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: That is not correct ProcessBuilder usage. Remove the single quotes entirely, and pass each word as a separate argument:  `new ProcessBuilder("nmcli", "device", "wifi", "connect", wifiName, "password", password)`